# jquery .on() method with selector not working for dynamic button

Tags: jquery, html

I have some code where I add a button dynamically to the page.

```
<a href=“#1" class="btn btn-default next">Next</a>
```

I am using the .on() method with the selector parameter but nothing is happening when I click the button. I saw that other people had a similar problem for dynamically added elements but they were missing the selector and adding it solved it.

```
$(".next").on("click", ".next", function() {

    alert(“next page");

});
```

I've put the button in the main body of my page when it loads and it works fine. It just doesn't work when it gets added to the page later.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$(".next").on("click", ".next", function() {`

to

`$(document).on("click", ".next", function() {`

Since you are dynamically creating the elements, using document will delegate the events on to the children elements so this helps to bubble up events on document level.

Comment: Glad it worked. You could accept the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that `ancestor` is the selector of an ancestor of the button in your html. Then:

```
$(ancestor).on("click", ".next", function() {
    alert("I have clicked on the button");
});
```

This works even if your button does not exist when this part runs. If you have nothing more specific for ancestor, then you can use `"body"`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

You can use document or body

```
$(document).on("click",".next", function() {
alert('button clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use onClick property of html

```js
function myFunction()
{
    alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```